# how can I get a really long "My Recent Documents" in windows xp?

Tags: windows-xp

I'd like to make "My Recent Documents" 100 or 200 files long.  It needn't be in the start menu.  It could be an alternative to "My Recent Documents", but one that can go that long. To quickly pop up links to 100 or 200 files most recently opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click `Start` > `run` and type

```
%userprofile%\recent
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Typing `recent` should be enough.

Comment: My Recent items only shows 91 items :-)

Comment: Problem is the sorting. Going to Recent and going to start..my recent documents. The ordering in the Recent folder, is not the same, and I'd like it to be.

Answer (score 0):

With your Registry backup in place, press the Windows key (Vista) or click Start > Run (XP), type regedit, and press Enter. In XP, navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Policies/Explorer. In Vista, the key you want to select is HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Explorer.

To change the number of files listed on this menu, double-click MaxRecentDocs in the same pane--or if there's no such key, right-click, select New > DWORD (32-bit) Value, name the new key MaxRecentDocs, and double-click it. Enter the number of documents you want to show in the Value Data field, and click OK.

(To disable Recent Documents:

In both versions, double-click NoRecentDocsHistory. If no such key exists, right-click in the right pane, select New > DWORD (32-bit) Value, and name the key NoRecentDocsHistory.

In the Value Data field, enter 1. When you restart Windows, your recent documents list will be history.)

Comment: can you include a screenshot?  if it's too private then you could rub out many characters from the filenames